# No encryption option on Huawei g510 and Android 4.1.1

Tags: security, encryption, huawei

I recently bought a Huawei g510 with Android 4.1.1 and I was going to encrypt it, but I just can't find the encryption option in the settings panel or any other place.

I looked around on the net but I just can't find a solution.

Is it a limit of the rom that comes with the phone?